# Woocommerce - Manipulate items SKU's before saving order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add 0 (zero) before each product's sku in every new order if the billing country is Spain.

I've managed to get this code to work:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'mbm_alter_sku', 10, 1 );
function mbm_alter_sku ($order) {
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $billing_country = $order->get_billing_country();
    
    if($billing_country == "ES"){
        // Get and Loop Over Order Items
        foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) {
            $product = $item->get_product();
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
            $product_sku = $product->get_sku();
            $sku_es = str_pad($product_sku, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $item->update_meta_data('sku', $sku_es);
            $item->save();
            //wc_update_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'sku', $sku_es , false );
        }
    }

    return $order;
    }
```

The only problem is that it saves the new value as a new meta key under the original SKU, so in the order post I have this:

```
SKU: 01
sku: 001
```

I've tried to do '_sku' as well, but I get the same result. How can I change the original product SKU key?

Comment: How about after create? because he instance of the items on the checkout_create_order are WC_Product class, but when you use the after order created, it will use WC_Order_Item https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item.html#method_update_meta_data

Comment: I'm doing it this way because I'm using an invoice plugin that takes the order as soon as it created and pass the data to the invoice system api.

Comment: Do the following: adjust the SKU for an existing product, than look at the order details page. You will see that the SKU changes to the SKU you modified. In other words, the SKU remains part of the product (product meta) and does not become part of the order (order meta). So either you write code that does this, but than you have to make sure that the plugin you use, uses your custom SKU and not the existing product SKU or you adjust it directly in that plugin where you temporarily store the product SKU in a variable + your prefix and then pass this variable against the existing product SKU

Comment: @7uc1f3r thank you! I'll see if there is a way to make the plugin take the custom SKU.